# Php array saving values only till 62 indices

Tags: php, arrays

I am sending a big array of 130+ indices from ajax to php. But while going to php, if i print, it became a 2D array with indices 63, 63, 6 respectively.
Below is snip

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 943900200
            [1] => 1297017000
            [2] => 1299436200
            [3] => 1302114600
            [4] => 1304879400
            [5] => 1307385000
         ................
            [60] => 1452105000
            [61] => 1454869800
            [62] => 1457375400
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 943900200
            [1] => 1297017000
            [2] => 1299436200
            [3] => 1302114600
            [4] => 1304879400
            [5] => 1307385000
           ......
            [61] => 1454869800
            [62] => 1457289000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1440441000
            [1] => 1443033000
            [2] => 1445970600
            [3] => 1445970600
            [4] => 1447007400
            [5] => 1448908200
        )

)
```

But i want them in a single D array...[0]--[127] together. I tried to copy them using foreach aswell. It copies the first 63 indices and stops. Any one please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `foreach` twice:

INTPUT (example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5031750
            [1] => 3972258
            [2] => 1673731
            [3] => 721866
            [4] => 4031885
            [5] => 1454990
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1115002
            [1] => 27608
            [2] => 3531620
            [3] => 4412066
            [4] => 4032217
            [5] => 2681734
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3360879
            [1] => 5190034
            [2] => 3452229
            [3] => 5112636
            [4] => 628357
            [5] => 4299124
        )

)
```

PHP Code:

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $key=>$sub){
    foreach($sub as $k => $v){
        $output[] = $v;
    }
}        
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5031750
    [1] => 3972258
    [2] => 1673731
    [3] => 721866
    [4] => 4031885
    [5] => 1454990
    [6] => 1115002
    [7] => 27608
    [8] => 3531620
    [9] => 4412066
    [10] => 4032217
    [11] => 2681734
    [12] => 3360879
    [13] => 5190034
    [14] => 3452229
    [15] => 5112636
    [16] => 628357
    [17] => 4299124
)
```

Comment: Oh,  yes! But could you explain why it turned out to 2D array while posting from ajax?

Comment: well, cannot answer you without having your code where you converting the data.

Comment: ajax:  jQuery.ajax({ url : "<?Php echo client_url().'investment/get_mf_summary_xirr/'; ?>"+'?req=json',data: {"xirr_dates_array" : xirr_dates_array,"xirr_amts_array": xirr_amts_array,"final_amt":total_net_mkt_val }, type : "post", dataType:"json", async : false})   ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, php :  $post = $this->input->post();
   $xirr_dates=$post['xirr_dates_array'];
   $xirr_amts=$post['xirr_amts_array'];

Comment: 1. add such code directly in your question. 2. this is a just the AJAX request so again have no idea what is the structure of all three arrays in your ajax `data` and what's going on before that.